# Angularjs post request

Tags: php, angularjs, post

When sending data from angularjs to php file, it works very well when not writing file name in my local host, but the moment I introduce the file name, the data is not sent and I get a 404 error.

What is mean is this:
When i use http://127.0.0.1/social/ the post request is working very well. But when using http://127.0.0.1/social/index.php I'm getting a 404 error. Here is my html section: 'index.php'

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/jsfile.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="socialApp">
<!-- Modal HTML for login -->
<div id="loginModal" class="modal fade" ng-controller="loginController">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <form method = "POST" action = "">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header text-center">
            <h3 class="modal-title">Login</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <h5 style="color: red;" id = "loginError"></h5>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" ng-model = "Username" class="form-control input input-lg" name = "username" placeholder="Email / Username" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" ng-model = "Password" class="form-control input input-lg" name = "password" placeholder="Password" required="required" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type = "submit" ng-click = "loginFunction()" class = "btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" name = "loginBtn" value = "Continue" />
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <h5><a href="#forgotPasswordModal" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal">Forgot password</a></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer text-center">
          <div class="form-group text-center">
            <h5>Not a member yet?<a href="#signUpModal" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss="modal"> Join now.</a></h5>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And below is my angularjs code 'js/jsfile.js'

```
var app = angular.module('socialApp',[]);
app.controller('loginController',['$scope','$http','$window', 
function($scope,$http,$window){
    $scope.loginFunction = function(){
        var what = "login";
        var username = $scope.Username
        var password = $scope.Password

        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: window.location.href + "php/savefetch.funct.php",
            data: {
                what:what,
                username:username,
                password:password
            },
            headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

        request.success(function (data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    };
}]);
```

I fetch the data on 'php/savefetch.funct.php' as below,

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input",true);
$request = json_decode($postdata);
@$what= $request->what;
@$username= $request->username;
@$password= $request->password;
echo $what." ".$username." ".$password;
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to `Stack Overflow`, Please consider using a [**MCVE** (**M**inimal **C**omplete **V**erifiable **E**xample)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: it's because of that: `window.location.href`. Better use a relative url there (like '../php/save.funct.php' - or whereever your script is located) . Or have a constant that points to your api-url and use that.

Comment: Thanks @Jeff. I'm now able to post